# How to Upgrade Second-Generation (2GP) Unlocked Package to Second-Generation (2GP) Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, unlocked-package, second-generation-packaging

Is it possible to deploy an `Unlocked` package to a production org, then upgrade the package to `Managed` and upgrade the package in the production org?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not tried this, but I don't think you could do.

The Salesforce DX Developer Guide:

- [Generate the Package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_create_pkg_base.htm?search_text=upgrade)

Says:

> You can’t change the package namespace or **package type** after you
> create the package.